# Is there a concept representing "connectedness" in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, axioms, magma

Consider an object, call it a *web*, that consists of a set $S$ equipped with a binary operation obeying these axioms:

$$
\forall\ a,b \in S\ \exists\ c \in S :a\ \bullet\ b=c
$$

$$
\forall\ a,b \in S\ \exists\ c \in S : a\ \bullet\ c=b
$$

The first axiom is just *closure*, but the second axiom is not one that I'm aware of in any of the literature I've checked. I'll call it *connectedness* in lieu of any formal language I'm unaware of. It does obviously arise as a logical consequence of *identity* and *invertibility* but those are not necessary. Case in point, consider the set $S=\{A,B,C,D\}$ and a binary operation $\bullet$ obeying the following multiplication table:

| $\bullet$ | $\boldsymbol{A}$ | $\boldsymbol{B}$ | $\boldsymbol{C}$ | $\boldsymbol{D}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $\boldsymbol{A}$ | $A$ | $C$ | $B$ | $D$ |
| $\boldsymbol{B}$ | $C$ | $A$ | $D$ | $B$ |
| $\boldsymbol{C}$ | $D$ | $B$ | $A$ | $C$ |
| $\boldsymbol{D}$ | $B$ | $D$ | $C$ | $A$ |

This set is obviously closed under this operation, however it has no identity element. This operation is also not associative:

$$
(C \bullet B) \bullet C = D \bullet C = C
$$

$$
C \bullet (B \bullet C) = C \bullet B = D
$$

This object is therefore not a monoid. It is a magma, because of the closure axiom all webs would be magmas, but the inverse isn't true. The set of all natural numbers is a magma under addition, but is not a web because $5+x=3$ has no solution in the natural numbers.

I would love to research this topic more but without knowing the correct terminology I haven't made much progress. Can anyone tell me if this concept is already known and what things to look for to find more information?

Comment: The example you give is a quasigroup, which is a concept related to what you're asking for.

Comment: I don't see why the first axiom is relevant, isn't it just closure actually?

Comment: To me, the way to view this is that the object you're defining also comes with a natural action on itself by right multiplication, and the axiom you are calling "connectedness" is the statement that this action is transitive.  (Since you are not assuming associativity "action" may not be the right technical term, but transitivity of actions is the thing your statement reminds me of).

Comment: Quasigroup requires $c$ to be unique, and applies to both sides. But on a finite set, if there is a solution for each side, this is a quasigroup. @LukasHeger

Comment: The closest term is "divisibility," but that requires answers $a\cdot c=b=d\cdot a,$ and that $c,d$ are unique. We could pick a name like "left-divisible" for a unique $c,$ but without uniqueness, I don't know another word. (Of course, on finite sets, if you have your property, it will be unique.) I dislike "connected," because it somehow gives preference to one side.

Comment: A simple example which is not a quasigroup is $x\cdot y =y$ for all $x,y.$ More generally, if $f:S\to S$ is an onto-function, $x\cdot y = f(y)$ on $S$ has your property. When $S$ is finite, it is necessarily a bijection, but if $S$ is infinite, you can have a non-bijection $f$ and thus the $c$ is not always unique.

Comment: An example which has the property on both sides and where the solutions are not unique is to consider $S=\mathbb Z[x],$ the ring of polynomials on the integers, and define $F(p(x))=\frac{p(x)-p(0)}{x},$ the left shift operator, and  define $P\cdot Q=F(P(x))+F(Q(x)).$

Comment: A word we could borrow from group actions is "transitive." I'd use the term "right-transitive" for your term, since in this case, the right term is seen as the action, acting on $a$ and sending to any element $b.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was only saying that the given example is actually a quasigroup and that it is a related concept, not actually the same.

Comment: Second law is fulfilled by a group.

Comment: @Wuestenfux not all groups, just transitive groups.

Answer (score 1):

One way to phrase your property is to define, if $S$ is your domain, functions $\phi_a:S\to S,$ with $\phi_a:x\mapsto a\bullet x.$ Then your property is that each $\phi_a$ is onto.

The property that each $\phi_a$ is one-to-one has a name, [left cancellative.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property)

But your sort-of dual property does not seem to have a name, at least not one listed on Wikipedia’s list of [binary operation properties.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Properties_of_binary_operations)

Cancellative might have a name because it applies to the foundational $\mathbb N^{>0}$ under both $+$ and $\times.$

---

One reason I dislike “connected” is that it feels related to graph theory, but a graph is connected if there is a sequence of edges. So in a graph theory sense, $a$ would be (left)-connected to $b$ if there was a $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ such that $a\bullet c_1\bullet\cdots\bullet c_n=b,$ where the operations are performed left to right.

I suggested in comments the term “right transitive,” in analogy to group actions. But that terminology might be almost too strongly tied to groups, giving an implication of associativity and inverses.

Another possible term, if we are thinking about graph theory, is “left-complete.” A directed graph is complete if all ordered pairs of nodes have an edge between the first and second node.

---

On a finite set $S,$ a function $f:S\to S$ is one-to-one if and only if it is onto. So for finite sets, left-cancellative is equivalent to left-complete. Together, they imply left-divisible. Same for the right- versions, of course. So, on a finite set, a (both left-and-right) complete operation implies that $(S,\bullet)$ is a quasigroup.